Dynaconf: how to set a key's default value for all elements in array
consider the following configuration file:
#settings.toml

default_datapath = "/data"

[[hosts]]
address = "192.168.10.4"
name = "foo"

[[hosts]]
address = "192.168.10.5"
name = "bar"

#...other hosts with no specified datapath...

[[hosts]]
address = "192.168.10.32"
name = "baz"
datapath = "/custom/data" #uses a custom datapath


How do I make it so that for all elements of the array,
settings.hosts[i].datapath returns the key's value if present, else default_datapath?
I've taken a look at validators with default values, but there doesn't seem to be a way to apply validators to array elements, else I would've gone for something like this:
#config.py
from dynaconf import Dynaconf, Validator

settings = Dynaconf(settings_files=['settings.toml'])

validators = [
    Validator(f"hosts[{i}].datapath", default=settings.default_datapath) 
    for i in range(len(settings.hosts))
]

settings.validators.register(*validators)
settings.validators.validate()
#DOESN'T WORK

The alternatives are:

handling the default behaviour in my application code (maybe by wrapping it into an HostConfiguration class to keep it DRY)
get rid of the default, and explicitly type it for all hosts

